# How to make array of values of objects

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input name="hello">value1
<input name="hello">value2
<input name="hello">value3
<input name="hello">value4


var a = getElementsByName('hello')
```

Now, how do I create an array that contains (value1,value2,value3,value4)?

I thought of using makeArray, but it returns just the objects not the values.

Comment: That doesn't look right... Inputs are self-closing tags. What type of inputs are they? The value is an attribute not a text node.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this like:
HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="hello1" value="value1">
<input type="text" id="hello2" value="value2">
<input type="text" id="hello3" value="value3">
<input type="text" id="hello4" value="value4">
```

JS:

```
alert('ready?');
var n = 4;
var arr = new Array(n);
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = document.getElementById('hello' + (i+1)).value;
}
alert(arr);
```

- [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Xyqz/)

Comment: Isn't there a simple workaround rather than accessing each and every element?

Comment: @Zim84 `<input arg="val" />` is XHTML, and `<input arg="val">` is HTML.  It's not vaild HTML either way, though.  Inputs are required to have an id, and a label with a for attribute.  Also a type is required.

Comment: Now it's starting to please me, keep it up, make that answer perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over them, or use map.

```
var items = Array.prototype.map.call(a, function(el){
    return el.nextSibling.textContent;
});
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6MLvU/)

---

```
var items = [];
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    items.push(a[i].nextSibling.textContent);
}
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/49QD9/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all your html should look like that:

```
<input name="hello1" value="value1" type="text" />
<input name="hello2" value="value2" type="text" />
<input name="hello3" value="value3" type="text" />
<input name="hello4" value="value4" type="text" />
```

I.e. if you are using text boxes your name attribute should be different. Otherwise you can't get the values. And of course the values are actually attributes. Here is a pure javascript code which could do what you want:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
var result = [];
for(var i=0; field=inputs[i]; i++) {
   result.push(field.value);   
}
alert(result);
```

And here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the example http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/nbmjG/

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs have to be like so: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RdYjx/)

```
<input name="hello" value="value1">
<input name="hello" value="value2">
<input name="hello" value="value3">
<input name="hello" value="value4">
```

Then following will return array of values:

```
var arr = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByName('hello'), function(elem){
   return elem.value;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use []

```
<input name="hello[]">value1</input>
<input name="hello[]">value2</input>
<input name="hello[]">value3</input>
<input name="hello[]">value4</input>
```

Comment: You need to use the "[]" after the name if you're using the same name for each input. That would make it easier to get all the values, with something like this:

var helloCount = document.getElementByName('hello[]');

for (var i = 0; i < helloCount; i++)
{
    //add value to array here
}